# How do I split a custom dataset into training and test datasets in Flux.jl?

Tags: julia, flux.jl

I have a custom dataset and I would like to split that dataset into a "training" and "test" set (also potentially a "validation" set if possible). How would I achieve this using Flux.jl or other Julia machine learning packages?

Comment: What is the type of the container you use to store your data set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can import the `TrainTestSplit` function from the Lathe package, as in:

```
using Lathe.preprocess: TrainTestSplit
```

and then implement it in your code like this for example:

```
dataset_id = TrainTestSplit(datasetmap[:], 0.8); #datasetmap is your label encoded matrix
```

Am assuming you're using Pluto notebook but, it should work in any other environment as well i,e jupyter, atom, etc.